# Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jarsigner.exe": CreateProcess

Tags: xml, eclipse, ant

I'm trying to run a buildXXX.xml file using ANT but i'm getting this error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Amira\Desktop\SaloméTMF\Salome TMF      
V3.1SourceCode\buildSOAPClient.xml
init:
prepare:
compile:
makesoapjar:
makeihmjar:
makecorejar:
makedatajar:
makeapijar:
makeloginjar:
maketoolsjar:
makeplugintoolsjar:
makeUpdatejar:
makebootjar:
makecodexjar:
makejar:
signjar:
   [signjar] Signing JAR: C:\Users\Amira\Desktop\SaloméTMF\Salome TMF    
   V3.1SourceCode\distrib\salome_tmf-soap-client\activation.jar to  
   C:\Users\Amira\Desktop\SaloméTMF\Salome TMF V3.1SourceCode\distrib\salome_tmf-soap- 
   client\activation.jar as salome_tmf

BUILD FAILED

C:\Users\Amira\Desktop\SaloméTMF\Salome TMF V3.1SourceCode\buildSOAPClient.xml:251:   
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jarsigner.exe": CreateProcess 
error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

Total time: 5 seconds
```

I made a search so i found that i should use JDK instead of JRE so i change it but the same error persist.

Any idea will be appreciated 
cheers

Answer (score 12):

The solution is to use JDK as installed JRE in eclipse  , and to set the JAVA-HOME variable to JDK path. 
Hope this help others :))

Comment: hi, just to add. the PATH folder should also be setup. this should be added %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

Comment: If you started the Ant build and accidentally had a JRE configured, you might have to run the ant task using "Run As > Ant Build..." and control/correct the JRE.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to change from 'Run in the same JRE as the workspace' to 'Separate JRE' **which is weird because these are the same JRE**.

Strange!

Answer (score 1):

I also selected 'Separate JRE' this allowed me to select the JDK rather than the JRE and that presumably enabled ANT to find the jarsigner in the JDK bin directory